# The value of one column can not contain in the other column and vice versa

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id bigint REFERENCES users(id),
    left_id bigint REFERENCES users(id) UNIQUE,
    right_id bigint REFERENCES users(id) UNIQUE,
);
```

`left_id` value can not contain in any row of `right_id`

`right_id` value can not contain in any row of `right_id`

How to create a constraint for this scenario?

Comment: *left_id value can not contain in any row of right_id* are you sure? Or is it **left_id value can not contain in any row of left_id**

Comment: Yes, I think... Should i worry? Because people positioned in the right side(right_id) of the user(id), cannot be positioned in the left side(left_id) of another user. This is a multilevel marketing system. Left_id value can not contain in any row of left_id is necessary too, that's why both columns are UNIQUE.